Should I Ask about implementation specific problems with a library or algorithm here or on StackOverflow
Is this site suitable for asking questions about problems found on an implementation of an algorithm in a library or this types of questions should be asked on StackOverflow.

I have a ready to deliver question just waiting for this question

Can you be more specific on what you mean about "problems found on an implementation of an algorithm"?

@mikeazo I Mean, If a compare two libraries implementing the same algorithm, let's say Blowfish with CBC or in my case with CTS, they both should output the same value given the same key, input and IV. I'm trying to port a legacy crypt routine and is not working and I need guidance to fix the issue since I'm not a cryptography expert, I want to show my steps (MVCE) and ask for experts to help me basically

Forgive my ignorance, what is MVCE?

@mikeazo MVCE

Thanks. I was thinking model-view-controller, what in the world is the E. :)

Here is what I would suggest. If you think the problem lies in the implementation, StackOverflow is probably the better place to ask. If you think your problem lies in a misunderstanding of some cryptographic primitive or concept, try to boil your example down to that specific cryptographic primitive or concept and ask about it. On our site, some pseudocode is fine, but the more code there is the more likely it is your question will get put on hold.
Worst case scenario you ask on one site, figure out it should have been on a different, and flag the question to have a moderator to move it. If you do post on StackOverflow, I suggest you add a comment on your meta post so we can follow it.

I've asked on StackOverflow

@EProgrammerNotFound Your question appears fine for Stack Overflow, since it seems to be mainly about the API and internals of some library. For comparison, here is an example of a recent question that would (and did) rightfully end up on Crypto.SE.
